# No Websocket response is obtained in JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter

1. If a WebSocket request-response Sampler is used, the next sampler fails.
2. The same requests pass on using WebSocket Single Write Sampler instead of WebSocket request-response Sampler.
3. Even when the WebSocket Single Write/Read Sampler passes, there is no response obtained for any of the samplers.

Please advice on what can be done. I am referring to the document -

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide/

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring the article and hitting the [`echo.websocket.org`](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html) I believe now you need to use `wss` protocol

If you're testing your own server unfortunately we are not able to help unless we see the

- full test plan
- [JMeter log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file (better with [debug logging for websocket plugin enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging), it can be done by adding the next line to log4j2.xml file in bin folder of your JMeter installation)

  ```
   <Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
  ```
- network dump from [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for both browser/application and JMeter